HTTP 504 error whenever I try to make a postgres destination connector on airbyte
I'm trying to set up a destination connector for postgres on Airbyte. I'm running the postgres database on a docker  container. However, after typing in all the database credentials on my local airbyte and hit "Set up Destination" I get a HTTP 504 error when it is testing the connection.
I tried to see if there was something wrong with the database credentials, but they look okay to me. I tried restarting docker to see if there was something wrong there, but that looks ok too. Please help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
